# Do GANs have constant running time?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-networks

After the model is trained, you just need to input random noise and the generator will output an image, does this mean GANs have constant running time ? I'm asking about both naïve GAN and variants of GAN

Comment: _constant running time_ with respect to what?

Comment: What do you mean? I just asked about the running time complexity of GAN, does the model have a constant running time or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit ill defined... usually when we want some bound on the running time, we have to say with respect to what

For example:

- sorting is O(nlogn) wrt the size of the input
- Transformer is O(n^2 * d) wrt to the number of input words (or number of patches)
- Diffusion models have O(1) complexity if we just consider the forward/backward diffusion

Now, as you can see, the problem is "hat are we considering for the measure"... sure if you encode GAN will Fully connected layers, you just have the n^2 for matrix multiplication... however, diffusion models have N step of diffusion to account for, but with the big-O notation taht N is canceled as it is just a constant

Comment: Is inference time different from running time, I read from the internet that GAN's inference time is faster than diffusion model ?

Comment: @David yes, but for the definition of computational complexity, you cannot see such difference, as they differ by a constant... GANs only need 1 forward pass, diffusion models usually in the order of tens of forward passes

Comment: So both run at constant time ? Because you can define the number of steps in diffusion model

Comment: @David exactly, from a computational point of view, since it's constant, it's omitted from the analysis (though, in real life, you have definitely to consider it)

Comment: I guess diffusion model is better than GAN in every aspect ?

Comment: @David depends, diffusion works if the assumption hold, like the gaussian distribution of the targets, GANs don't make any assumption on the distribution